# Is there any way to instantiate a Class<C<A,B>> object in java?

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

I'm trying to use Hibernate and TypedQuery in java.

The method I'm trying to call has a signature of

```
<T> TypedQuery<T>   createQuery(String qlString, Class<T> resultClass)
```

I want to call it like bellow but with null replaced by a real instance.

```
 Class<Tuple2<Date,String>> cls=null;
 List<Tuple2<Date,String>> books=em.createQuery("select new io.vavr.Tuple2(date,title) from Book where publicationdate > '2008-01-01'",cls).getResultList();
```

the above code compiles but obviously chrashes with a null pointer exception.

If my understanding of erasure is correct this would work as long as I get an instance of the Class object as all generic type information would be lost at runtime anyway.

Is there any way I can get an instance of Class that i can assign to the variable cls so that this code will work?

Comment: Instead of `Class<Tuple2>` you could use `Tuple2.class`. Besides that, there is no `Tuple2<Date,String>.class` there is only  `Tuple2.class`. You could create a `class DateStringTuple extends Tuple2<Date,String>` though, thus you could directly use `DateStringTuple.class` in `createQuery()`.

Comment: @Thomas that does not solve the problem, only moves it. Doing that results in a compiler error: incompatible types: java.util.List<io.vavr.Tuple2> cannot be converted to java.util.List<io.vavr.Tuple2<java.util.Date,java.lang.String>>

Comment: Well, the first part wasn't about a solution but about why what you want to do is not possible. You could use a raw type (via a cast to `List` only) but that would not ensure that the tuples returned have the types `Date` and `String`.

Comment: Better use a custom class for specific queries like that, instead of the generic Tuple which is designed for simple "quick and dirty" cases, but if you still want to keep that generic, just use Tuple2.class, and cast to (Tuple2<String,Date>). remove the confusing line " Class<Tuple2<Date,String>> cls=null;"

Comment: Consider using the more abstract `Type`.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for your suggestion of extending the class. What I ended up with is. (above method) public static class DateStringPair extends MutablePair<Date,String>{public DateStringPair(Date d,String s){super(d,s);}} (inside the method) List<DateStringPair> books=em.createQuery("select new com.example.ConnectionAndQueryTest$DateS
tringPair(publicationDate,title) from Book where publicationDate > '2008-01-01'",DateStringPair.class).getResultList(
); Feel free to post as an answer as there does not seems to be a way to do this in the way I first attempted.

Comment: Since you developed the solution in the end why don't you post it as an answer? You should be able to accept it after a short wait period then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Thomas comments on the first post I came upp with the following.

While it dies not seems to be a way to instantiate such a Class object a relativly readable solution can be achived with subclassing.

In the class where the code resides add outside any function

```
public static class DateStringPair extends Pair<Date,String>{
      public DateStringPair(Date d,String s){super(d,s);}
}
```

And then the call becomes

```
List<DateStringPair> books=em.createQuery(
        "select new com.example.ConnectionAndQueryTest$DateStringPair(publicationDate,title) from Book where publicationDate > '2008-01-01'"
    ,DateStringPair.class).getResultList( );
```

this have the limitation that the Pair class must not be final.

While not as flexible as full generics support in the query readability of the query can be maintained without that much fuss.